# Is there a way to execute .map recursively for every array in an array in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have this array which repeats recursively:

```
 [
    {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "Id",
          "Property": "Placeholder",
          "Children": [
           {
             "Name": "Child Id",
             "Property": "Placeholder",
             "Children": null
           }
          ]
        }
    }
]
```

To get the structure I want I currently have this:

```
const fixed = data.map(item => item = {
        data: {
            name: item.Name,
        },
        children: item.Children.map(child => child = {
            name: child.Name,
        })
    }
  )
```

Is there a way to repeat my initial array.map recursively for each child array?

Comment: Side note : that's not how you use `.map()`. It is supposed to _return_ an object, that will replace the original one in the array. You are not returning anything, but assigning the new object to the old object. It works, but it's not what `.map()` was made for.

Comment: What do you want to get? Give us an example of output data.

Comment: @JeremyThille noted I wanted to replace the original item in the example

Comment: @BülentAkgül thanks for the help I accepted the first answer as it gave me the output I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution, based on the output I *believe* you want:

```js
const array = [{
  "Name": "Test",
  "Children": [{
    "Name": "Id",
    "Property": "Placeholder",
    "Children": [{
      "Name": "Child Id 1",
      "Property": "Placeholder",
      "Children": null
    }, {
      "Name": "Child Id 2",
      "Property": "Placeholder",
      "Children": [{
        "Name": "Child Id 3",
        "Property": "Placeholder",
        "Children": null
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];


const map = (arr) => {
  return arr ? arr.map(fix) : null;
}

const fix = (item) => {
  return {
    data: {
      name: item.Name
    },
    children: map(item.Children),
  };
}

console.log(map(array))
```

Or as suggested below, use shortands:

```
const map = arr => arr ? arr.map(fix) : null;

const fix = item => ({
  data: {
    name: item.Name
  },
  children: map(item.Children),
});
```

Comment: Useless `return` statements, for instance the `map()` function could simply be written `const map = arr => arr ? arr.map(fix) : null;`

Comment: @JeremyThille matter of taste I guess.

Comment: Yes, I like minimalism :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use a base case where we check if the `Children` property is `null`,if so recursion stops and we return the `Name`:

```js
const data = [{"Name": "Test", "Children": [{"Name": "Id","Property": "Placeholder","Children": [{"Name": "Child Id","Property": "Placeholder","Children": null }] }] }];

const flattenData = (data) => {
    return data.map(d => {
    //Base case, recursion stops here
    if(!d.Children){
      return d.Name;
    }
    //Continue recursion
    return {data: {name: d.Name},  children: flattenData(d.Children) }
   });
}
console.log(flattenData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that transforms children. If the child has other children, then the function will call itself to transform them recursively.

```js
const input = [
    {
        "Name": "Test",
        "Children": [
            {
                "Name": "Id",
                "Property": "Placeholder",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Child Id",
                        "Property": "Placeholder",
                        "Children": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

const transformChildren = children => children.map(child => ({
    name: child.Name,
    children: child.Children ? transformChildren(child.Children) : null
}));

const output = input.map(item => ({
    data: {
        name: item.Name,
    },
    children: item.Children ? transformChildren(item.Children) : null
}))

console.log(output)
```